# TSQL combine two count queries with slightly different where clause into one output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, conditional-statements, sql-server-2014

I would like to combine the two TSQL queries below into one query.

```
  -------------------------------------
   USE [ourDB]
  -------------------------------------
  Select   --
 id
 , count(id) as count_30_days_or_less
  --
  FROM Col1 c1  WITH (NOLOCK)
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  LEFT JOIN Col2 c2  WITH (NOLOCK)  
  ON (c1.id = c2.foreign_id)
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  WHERE
  (
      (DATEDIFF( dd, cast(c1.ourDateTime as Date), cast(GETDATE() as Date)  ) <= 30)
  )
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY id
  -------------------------------------
  Select   --
 id
 , count(id) as count_45_days_or_less
  --
  FROM Col1 c1  WITH (NOLOCK)
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  LEFT JOIN Col2 c2  WITH (NOLOCK)  
  ON (c1.id = c2.foreign_id)
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  WHERE
  (
      (DATEDIFF( dd, cast(c1.ourDateTime as Date), cast(GETDATE() as Date)  ) <= 45)
  )
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY id
  -------------------------------------
```

Each of the first query will give the format
id count_YY_days_or_less

---

The goal is to output the query in the format:
id count_30_days_or_less count_45_days_or_less

---

Note:  It is potentially possible that in addition to differing counts, *more* id instances could show up in the column for the second count.

### The accepted answer is correct.

I have a "part two":
Part 2: Is there any way to ensure that the c1.id is "distinct" in the counts returned from the above query?

### (See comment of accepted answer for "part two" answer)

This should be version independent, but I use Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) - 12.0.6024.0 (X64)   Sep  7 2018 01:37:51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    sum(case when c1.ourdatetime >= dateadd(day, -30, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else 0 end) count_30_days_or_less,
    count(*) as count_45_days_or_less
from col1 c1
left join col2 c2  on c1.id = c2.foreign_id
where c1.ourdatetime >= dateadd(day, -45, cast(getdate() as date))
group by id
order by id
```

The query filters on the last 45 days of data (note that I simplified your code to not use date functions on the table column - this is more efficient). Then, we use a conditional expression to count how many rows per `id` are within 30 days only.

Comment: Part 2: Is there any way to ensure that the c1.id is "distinct" in the counts returned from the above query?

Comment: @JosephDoggie: I think `count(distinct case when c1.ourdatetime >= dateadd(day, -30, cast(getdate() as date)) then id end) count_30_days_or_less,
  count(distinct id) as count_45_days_or_less`

Comment: The answer to "part two" in the comment above is also correct.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer to include the answer to 'part two', but apparently it was NOT approved.  If you wish, you may edit-in the answer to 'part two' from the comment above, for completeness.